# OpenGL Stereo View -- How to use GLM Math library for horizontal offset

Tags: c++, math, opengl, linear-algebra, glm-math

I'm trying to use the GLM mathematics library to warp the projection matrix such that multiple cameras (e.g. a left eye and a right eye) are viewing the same view, but the camera frustum is distorted.

This is what I am trying to do with my cameras using GLM:

image [image]

Note: One of the challenges I have for my camera, is that I only have in my OpenGL Graphics API a read-only view matrix and projection matrix. So even once I have the view and projection matrix, I can only move my camera using x,y,z for eye position, and then yaw,pitch,roll for view direction. Then I have standard OpenGL calls, but I am not sure how to shift or warp the projection matrix as shown below.

I think this second picture also accurately shows what I am trying to achieve with OpenGL.

Any tips on how to approach this problem? Do I need to implement a special lookAt function, or is there something built into GLM that can help me compute the right view?

[image]

Comment: *"I can only move my camera using x,y,z for eye position,"* - To achieve the above affect, you need to move the camera position and change (tilt) the line of sight.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: @genpfault what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this is:

- Assume that X is the position of the "nose" (the half point between the 2 eyes).
- Let V be the direction orthogonal to  the left eye - right eye line.
- The function X + t * V describes the "line of sight" in your last
  picture.
- Take t > 0 and set that as your look at point  P/
- Create 2 cameras with centers at the eyes, both with the exact same up direction, then use glm::lookat to look at P.